# how to sort an NSArray of nested NSArrays by array count?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, nsmutablearray, nsarray

I have an NSArray that contains nested NSArrays. Im looking for a way to sort the parent array according to the object count of the nested arrays in ascending order. so if `[array1 count]` is 4, `[array2 count]` is 2 and `[array3 count]` is 9,  i would get : array2, array1, array3...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There are a few solutions, one of which is:

```
NSSortDescriptor *sd = [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"@count"
                                                     ascending:YES];
NSArray *sds = [NSArray arrayWithObject:sd];
NSArray *sortedArray = [array sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:sds];
```

Comment: @Sam Indeed, and you can always use the `@count` collection operator for KVC compliant collections.

Comment: Ah, my apologies. I wasn't aware of that / misread your code.  Very cool!

Comment: works great!.. i tried it earlier before asking the question but i was using `@"count"` as key and it was crashing... whats the secret with `@"@count"`???

Comment: @KDaker `NSArray` doesn’t have a KVC compliant key called `count`. There is an instance method called `-count` but it isn’t a key in the KVC sense. That said, in Cocoa collections you can use special key paths called [collection operators](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/KeyValueCoding/Articles/CollectionOperators.html), and `@count` is one of them.

Answer (score 1):

```
static NSInteger MONSortObjectsAscendingByCount(id lhs, id rhs, void* ignored) {
/* error checking omitted */
    const NSUInteger lhsCount = [lhs count];
    const NSUInteger rhsCount = [rhs count];

    if (lhsCount < rhsCount) {
        return NSOrderedAscending;
    }
    else if (lhsCount > rhsCount) {
        return NSOrderedDescending;
    }
    else {
        return NSOrderedSame;
    }
}

/* use if mutable, and you wnat it sorted in place */
- (void)sortUsingFunction:(NSInteger (*)(id, id, void *))compare context:(void *)context;

/* else use */
- (NSArray *)sortedArrayUsingFunction:(NSInteger (*)(id, id, void *))compare context:(void *)context;
```

Comment: A function whose name doesn’t start with `MON`? Who are you and what have you done to Justin?

Comment: ugggghhhhhhhhhh!!!!!!! =p Justin has a headache today, and the build was finished. thanks for pointing that out -- i've fixed it now =)