# How to sort Arrays according to length inside Main Array

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsmutablearray, nsarray

I have an `NSMutableArray` `mainArray`, On every index of this `mainArray` I have other arrays of length 2, 3 or 4.

I want to sort `mainArray` in such way that array inside with bigger length comes on top of `mainArray`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5838480/how-to-sort-an-nsarray-of-nested-nsarrays-by-array-count) , this might help

```
NSSortDescriptor *sd = [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"@count"
                                                 ascending:NO];
NSArray *sds = [NSArray arrayWithObject:sd];
NSArray *sortedArray = [array sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:sds];
```

It will sort `mainArray` in such a way that inner array with higher count will come on top.

Comment: Are you passing `mainArray` in place of `array` in code?

Comment: Yes I passed my main array in place of array.

Comment: array on index 1 has larger count so I want to sort it on top.

Comment: @count is Count property of an array.

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```
NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor;
sortDescriptor = [[[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:[subArray count]
                                              ascending:NO] autorelease];
NSArray *sortDescriptors = [NSArray arrayWithObject:sortDescriptor];

[myArray sortUsingDescriptors:sortDescriptors];
```

`subArray` will be `inside array`

`[subArray count]` will do the trick.

Comment: but I don't have just one  subArray, I have several subArray, which subarray count will it take.

Comment: @S.J : can you post sample json data?

Comment: I have no json data. its like mianArray[0] = {a,b} ... mianArray[1] = {x,y,z} ...

Comment: Now in mainarray at index 1 the length of array is greater, so I want it on top of main array.

Comment: @S.J : so data will be like this... right? `[{1,2}, {1,2,3}, {1,2,3,4}]`

Comment: yes exactly and after sorting 1,2,3,4 must be on index 0 ... 1,2,3 on index 1 and 1,2 on index 2.